# How to make a regex to remove a string from text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to remove a string from the Text.

Here is the text sample:-

> This is sample data. Remove me **Check Type: TOU** from text. This is sample data.

The string I am always looking for is something like this:-

**Check Type: TOU**

- **Check Type:**  = always same including colon (:)
- **Then always a Space**
- **TOU** = Is a not always same it can be anything but its always a one word. So always looking for it untill next space.

Here is the code i am trying but :(

```
var startIndex = Text.IndexOf("Check Type:");
var firstPart = Text.Substring(startIndex, Text.IndexOf(' '));
var startIndex1 = startIndex + firstPart.Length + 1;
var finaltext = Text.Substring(startIndex1, Text.IndexOf(' '));
```

Comment: Given your example, what should `finaltext` equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regular expression would be:

```
@"Check Type: \w+ "
```

This will match a literal `Check Type:`, followed by a space, followed by one or more [word characters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WordCharacter), followed by a space.

For example:

```
var finalText = Regex.Replace(Text, @"Check Type: \w+ ", "");
```

This could be generalize to accept any sort of whitespace characters (including tabs and newlines) by substituting spaces for `\s`. You can also allow this to find matches when this appears at the end of the string by making the final space optional with `?`:

```
@"Check\sType:\s\w+\s?"
```

Comment: whitespace like `space` is represented by `\s` in regex.

Comment: @Dan-o Yes but OP is specifically talking about space characters.

Comment: Unless your using the [`IgnorePatternWhitespace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) option, a space in the pattern should match a space in the text.

Comment: @Dan-o It's a good point though, I've included a note about space vs. `\s`.

Answer (score -2):

var firstPart = Text.replace("Check Type: [a-zA-Z]+", "");